# Need some stress testing focused example of ReactJS

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, reactjs

Looking for a sample in Asp.Net MVC coupled with ReactJS on front end that makes use of heavy data changes on UI.

Need this in order to ascertain performance of React when lot of json data is pushed from backend to front end.

Tried to find such example on different sites but couldn't find one so far. Most examples I found are trivial. I need one that mimics some real world scenario.

[Update] Actually I want to have some piece of React code using which I can do sort of stress testing in JavaScript.

Comment: A real world example is Facebook.com  they may heavy use of React elements on their pages.

Comment: Examples are [flipboard](http://engineering.flipboard.com/2015/02/mobile-web/), [khan academy](http://benalpert.com/2013/06/09/using-react-to-speed-up-khan-academy.html) and [hipchat](https://developer.atlassian.com/blog/2015/02/rebuilding-hipchat-with-react/). Links are pointing to their engineering blogs where they are explained their use of react.

Comment: I m asking for some code sample. Actually I want to do sort of stress testing in JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it helps, but you can take a look at [gremlin.js](https://github.com/marmelab/gremlins.js) for monkey/fuzz testing.

Comment: Really impressive. Nice one